# Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitOnCompleted'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, mailchimp

After adding this method (first test on C# async keyword in my life) to my project I get the error below, why?

```
public async Task<Member> AddOrUpdate(DownloadFormModel model)
{
   IMailChimpManager mailChimpManager = new MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailChimpKey"]);

   Member member = new Member {EmailAddress = model.Email, Status = Status.Subscribed};
   member.MergeFields.Add("NAME", model.Name);

   return (await mailChimpManager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailChimpDownloadListID"], member));
}
```

Error inside VStudio 2015 after compilation:

> Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitOnCompleted'

My project is a ASP.NET MVC 4 targeting .NET Framework 4.5 (just upgraded from 4.0) and I'm trying to integrate [MailChimp.NET v3](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net) inside it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Created a brand new MVC WebApplication .NET 4.5 project in VStudio 2015 and the same method compiles without errors. What should I check?

Comment: Do you have the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` nuget package, which shouldn't be needed with .NET 4.5 and may be causing issues?

Comment: Added `Microsoft.Blc` and `Microsoft.Blc.Build` without succeeding. `Microsoft.Blc.Async` is not listed in the VStudio NuGet manager.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't need any of those when you're targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: No I didn't have them, sorry.

Comment: Okay, well as this is the first time you've ever used async, I'd start a fresh console app and try to write an async method which just awaits the result of `Task.Delay`, for example. Check that *that* works before you start with MailChimp.

Comment: I can compile these samples without problems: http://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Comment: Okay, so it's only the use of MailChimp that causes problems? If so, you might want to try removing it from the project and readding it, as it may well add a different assembly from within the package.

Comment: I suspect that ASP.NET MVC project is the problem instead...

Comment: Well you should be able to find that out easily enough: try each in isolation in turn. (Console app + Mailchimp, ASP.NET v4 app without Mailchimp.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was this line in the *package.config* file and more in general a number of lines in the same file still reporting `targetFramework="net40"`:

```
<package id="AsyncCTP" version="0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
```

After retargeting the project to .NET framework 4.5 I should have called

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

for each package in the list.